# Why does this JQuery code give me a undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id;
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(id);
});
```

I am using the above code to get a selected option from a dropdown and then use that variable as a global variable in all my JS files. However, this is giving me an `undefined` in the console. How do I get `id` to behave as a global variable in all my JS files.?

Comment: First: click is an event, you are logging id after the event registration not execution.
Second: use javascript namespacing pattern rather than put it under the global scope.

Comment: also take a look at: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need id to be a global variable, I can't see how that would be advantageous at all.

It's logging undefined because it's undefined when you call it, you only set the value after the click event has been called.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = "foo";
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());

        console.log(id); // This will now log whatever was in your text value
    });
    console.log(id); //This will now log 'foo'
});
```

This is what's happening with your code at the minute

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //You're not passing id a value, so it gets initialised as undefined.
    var id; 

    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());

        console.log(id); // This will now log whatever was in your text value
    });

    //The click event hasn't been called yet, so id is still undefined.
    console.log(id);

    //You've only assigned a click event above, you didn't call it, id will 
    //not get set until '.dropdown-menu a' has been clicked. 
});
```

Although outside of the scope of your question, in answer to your comment,  to make id a global variable, I would add one global variable, rather than just a random 'id' property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var App = window.App || (window.App = {});

    App.id = "foo";

    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        App.id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());

        console.log(App.id); // This will now log whatever was in your text value
    });
    console.log(App.id); //This will now log 'foo'
});




//In some other JS file on your webpage / in scope
var App = window.App || (window.App = {});

console.log(App.id); //This should log the ID, providing it was called after the above code.
```

One of the most important reasons why adding 'id' as a global is a bad idea, is that you can end up populating the global namespace with lots of arbitrary values, there's no structure, thus it's hard to maintain the code, and you risk overwriting an important property on the global namespace, which could cause undefined behaviour in your website/App.

Having a single global object is an acceptable way of utilising the global namespace, without risking the accidental overrides to other variables, and it's also a lot easier to debug your Apps variables.

A single log of the App object (call it whatever you like), will (presumably) log only the variables your app has created, thus you're not having to look through many other variable to find yours.

If you used my code suggestion above, compare these two logs:

```
console.log(window.App); 

console.log(window); //The global namespace
```

You should see that the first log prints you out a nice, clean object with just your variable "id" inside, you should see a tonne of variables in the second log, in fact, you may of even had to scroll down in the console to find your 'id' variable.

Comment: I am working with an API and want to use a ID that I get via JSON to behave as a global variable in all my other JS Files. So how do I make the `console.log(id); // This will now log whatever was in your text value` to behave as a global variable?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. This is being showed in the console when I use `console.log(window.App.id);` in my other JS file.

Comment: I have fixed an error where, if you called the other file snippet before window.App was created it would throw an error. Check the snippet again.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure that the log for window.App is placed inside a document ready function, just like you're original. In the other script file, add a setTimeout(function () { console.log(window.App); }, 2000) to test.

Comment: This solved my problem.Thank you. Can you please tell me what `var App = window.App || (window.App = {});` this is exactly or link me to some documentation?

Comment: What that expression says is "var app = [ if window.App exists, app = that, if window.App does not exist, first create it (as an empty object), then assign that value to the variable."

Comment: Essentially it means that the first time you ever call that statement, it will create the window.App object, as window.App will equal undefined the first time, this will trigger the OR condition (||), thus creating the object. Any future calls to this won't trigger the OR condition because window.App would now be created. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

`id` is a local variable available only withing your `$(document).ready()` function. If you want to have global access, then define it outside of any functions. This should fix your problem. You can read more about scopes [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a wrong answer. `id` is still visible inside the click handler function. It is just not initialized at the time it is logged. Did you even read the article you linked?

Answer (score 1):

your code will be undefined is right. because when page load but user don't click on $('.dropdown-menu a') and then no value for id variable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id;
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(id);
});
```

If you still want to see value of variable you can fix like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id;
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

Hope this help!!! =)

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of `id` changes only when you click `$('.dropdown-menu a')` But in your ready function you print out without any condition. You defined the `var id` inside the `ready` function and then defined a function that occurs only on a click event and then print out the `id`. In between the definition of the var `id` and the printing its value no click occured so nothing changed therefore it's still undefined. If you want to see what's the value of `id` after clicking modify your code to :

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
    id = $(this).text();
    $('#selected').text($(this).text());
    console.log(id);
});
```

This will print the value in console after clicking  `.dropdown-menu a`

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalScope = globalScope || {};

$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
        globalScope.id = $(this).text();
        $('#selected').text($(this).text());
        console.log(globalScope.id);
    });   
});
```

warning: click is an event, you are logging id after the event registration not execution. Put it in your event if you want to log it every click, after the new association.

use javascript namespacing pattern rather than delcare it out of the function, just to prevent future issues and to orgainze your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()   // jquery
{
   $("#id Your Checkbox").Change(function()
    {
           var id = $(this).Val();
           // now , you can use of id.
           $("#test").text(id);
    });
});
```